# How to dynamically select the database(or "schema"), in a Sequelize model?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, multi-tenant

I'm building a **multi tenant** application, using Nodejs, Seuqelize and Mysql.

I've decided on an approach where each tenant gets a separate logical database(From what i understand, in Postgres this would be called a "schema", but in Mysql it's simply a "database"). I chose this approach, because in my case, databases would need to be created **after** the Node process already started, and a DB connection was made, and there is no way to configure them in advance.

I do not know how to dynamically(during an HTTP request) tell a Sequelize model, which database should be used, for the particular query.

For example, let's say i have this GET/photo/ route:

```
router.get('photo/', async function (req, res) {
    const tenantId = req.user.id//Assume the auth middleware provides a tenant id.
    try {
        const records = await Photo.findAll()//Need to tell the Photo model, which database/schema this
        //should be queried in      
        
        res.json(records);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.sendStatus(500)
    }

})
```

Of course, if i were using raw queries, i would just say

> `SELECT * FROM ${tenantId}.photo`

But if i'm using Sequelize, i want to actually enjoy its full features.

How can i tell the Photo model, which database to use? Let me clarify again, that **i'm not talking about a physical database**, but just a logical one. The host is the same host, **and i have only one connection**. The initial "database" argument to the Sequelize config is a database that holds all tenants, with references to their respective databases.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a new instance of `Sequelize` for each of the schemas you want to create a connection for. The Models will need to be dynamically defined so that correct `sequelize` instance is passed in when the Model is created and subsequently returned.

1. getPhotoModelFor(tenantId) - try to get a Model for a particular tenant
2. should probably check a cache to see if it already exists, will need to handle expirations, etc
3. if the Model isn't in the cache for this tenant, get the `sequelize` instance for this tenant and create if it doesn't exist
4. define the model using this `sequelize` instance and cache
5. return Model and use it for queries.